# ggplot2: geom_bar fill colour; how to change to different grouping of data

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, geom-bar

I have the following dataset showing fiscal period, product and sum of transactions:

```
app$FISCAL_PERIOD <-c(201604,201604,201604,201605,201605,201605,201606,201606,201606,201607,201607,201607,201608,201608,201608,201609,201609,201610,201610,201611,201611)

app$Product <- c("Product 1","Product 3","Other","Product 1","Product 3","Other","Product 1","Product 3","Other","Product 1","Product 3","Other","Product 1","Product 3","Other","Product 2","Product 3","Product 2","Product 3","Product 2","Product 3")

app$sum_trans<-c(78,23410,1946,84,29532,417,16,30364,129,305,32386,584,424,20873,274,20,20929,470,19261,10,6131)
```

I have plotted this as a dodged bar chart in ggplot2. Ggplot is automatically assigning colours to each fill so that each fiscal period is a different colour.

```
ggplot(data = app, aes(x = Product, y = sum_trans, fill = as.factor(FISCAL_PERIOD))) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", colour="black")
```

[image: Plot drawn by ggplot code above]

What I need is to show each product having the same colour and the fill variable not affecting the chart. 
I.e. I would like all product 1 fiscal period data to be one colour and all product 3 fiscal period data to be another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the fill variable as `product` as that defines the color you want and specify an additional group variable as `FISCAL_PERIOD` so that each bar will still be segmented by year:

```
ggplot(data = app, aes(x = Product, y = sum_trans, fill = Product, group = FISCAL_PERIOD)) + 
   geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", colour="black")
```

[image]

Comment: This is awesome, thanks. Is there a way to label the periods in any way? on the x asis?

Comment: You can use `geom_text()` for labeling but that will make the text very crowded. You may need to think of another way to do this. For labeling, add `geom_text(aes(label = FISCAL_PERIOD), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), vjust = -0.25)` to your plot should give you all the years on each bar. Adjust the parameters accordingly.